# How can I get all the records in a table where any value of an associated table is in a given array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I think if I had a better idea how to word this question, I would have been able to find an answer already... Anyways, I have a table called Vendors that has a many-to-many relationship with a table called Basins. I would like to be able to retrieve all the vendors that have at least one basin in an array of basins that is passed in as input.

So if I had three vendors like:

```
vendor1.basins = [Basin.first, Basin.second]
vendor2.basins = [Basin.second, Basin.third]
vendor3.basins = [Basin.third, Basin.fourth]
```

And I wanted to get all the vendors containing anything from `[Basin.first, Basin.fourth]`, I would get both `vendor1` and `vendor3`. If the array was `[Basin.first, Basin.second]`, I would get both `vendor1` and `vendor2`. I thought `select` might be the way to go here, but everything I've tried has been flagrantly wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Rails >= v4.0.0.

You can get vendors like:

```
Vendor.joins(:basins).where(basins: { id: [Basin.first.id, Basin.fourth.id] })
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need. In case anyone else stumbles upon this and needs the last piece that I needed for a variable array, this is what I've ended up with: `Vendor.joins(:basins).where(basins: {id: basin_array.map{|basin| basin[:id]}})`

Comment: @PawanAgarawal: We can also do `Vendor.joins(:basins).where(basins: {id: basin_array})`, rails will do the rest.(Tested on Rails master branch)

Answer (score 0):

You can add scope to Vendor model:

```
scope :foo, ->(basins_arr){ joins(:basins).
   where(basins: { id: basins_arr.collect(&:id)})
```